# Showing unknown characters when excel forced to download in PhpExcel codeigniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, header, phpexcel

I am using PhpExcel to download reports as excel in my codeigniter application. When I try to download my report its showing some characters on the browser instead of downloading the file. This has worked fine in localhost but not working in the server. I dont know whats the problem. Here is my code:

**View**

```
        <div class="box-content">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">

        <p class="introtext"><?= lang('customize_report'); ?></p>

        <div id="form">

        <?php echo form_open("reports/getSalesaccReport"); ?>
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="reference_no"><?= lang("reference_no"); ?></label>
        <?php echo form_input('reference_no', (isset($_POST['reference_no']) ? $_POST['reference_no'] : ""), 'class="form-control tip" id="reference_no"'); ?>

        </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="user"><?= lang("created_by"); ?></label>
        <?php
        $us[""] = "";
        foreach ($users as $user) {
        $us[$user->id] = $user->first_name . " " . $user->last_name;
        }
        echo form_dropdown('user', $us, (isset($_POST['user']) ? $_POST['user'] : ""), 'class="form-control" id="user" data-placeholder="' . $this->lang->line("select") . " " . $this->lang->line("user") . '"');
        ?>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="customer"><?= lang("customer"); ?></label>
        <?php echo form_input('customer', (isset($_POST['customer']) ? $_POST['customer'] : ""), 'class="form-control" id="customer" data-placeholder="' . $this->lang->line("select") . " " . $this->lang->line("customer") . '"'); ?>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="biller"><?= lang("biller"); ?></label>
        <?php
        $bl[""] = "";
        foreach ($billers as $biller) {
        $bl[$biller->id] = $biller->company != '-' ? $biller->company : $biller->name;
        }
        echo form_dropdown('biller', $bl, (isset($_POST['biller']) ? $_POST['biller'] : ""), 'class="form-control" id="biller" data-placeholder="' . $this->lang->line("select") . " " . $this->lang->line("biller") . '"');
        ?>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="warehouse"><?= lang("warehouse"); ?></label>
        <?php
        $wh[""] = "";
        foreach ($warehouses as $warehouse) {
        $wh[$warehouse->id] = $warehouse->name;
        }
        echo form_dropdown('warehouse', $wh, (isset($_POST['warehouse']) ? $_POST['warehouse'] : ""), 'class="form-control" id="warehouse" data-placeholder="' . $this->lang->line("select") . " " . $this->lang->line("warehouse") . '"');
        ?>
        </div>
        </div>
        <?php if($this->Settings->product_serial) { ?>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="form-group">
        <?= lang('serial_no', 'serial'); ?>
        <?= form_input('serial', '', 'class="form-control tip" id="serial"'); ?>
        </div>
        </div>
        <?php } ?>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="form-group">
        <?= lang("start_date", "start_date"); ?>
        <?php echo form_input('start_date', (isset($_POST['start_date']) ? $_POST['start_date'] : ""), 'class="form-control datetime" id="start_date"'); ?>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="form-group">
        <?= lang("end_date", "end_date"); ?>
        <?php echo form_input('end_date', (isset($_POST['end_date']) ? $_POST['end_date'] : ""), 'class="form-control datetime" id="end_date"'); ?>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
        <div
        class="controls"> <?php echo form_submit('submit_report', $this->lang->line("submit"), 'class="btn btn-primary"'); ?> </div>
        </div>
        <?php echo form_close(); ?>

        </div>
```

**Controller**

```
        function getSalesaccReport()
        {
        if ($this->input->post('customer')) {
        $customerid = $this->input->post('customer');
        } else {
        $customerid = NULL;
        }
        echo $customerid;
        if ($this->input->post('biller')) {
        $biller = $this->input->post('biller');
        } else {
        $biller = NULL;
        }
        if ($this->input->post('warehouse')) {
        $warehouse = $this->input->post('warehouse');
        } else {
        $warehouse = NULL;
        }
        if ($this->input->post('start_date')) {
        $start_date = $this->input->post('start_date');
        } else {
        $start_date = NULL;
        } echo $start_date;
        if ($this->input->post('end_date')) {
        $end_date = $this->input->post('end_date');
        } else {
        $end_date = NULL;
        } echo $end_date;
        if ($start_date) {
        $start_date = $this->sma->fld($start_date);
        $end_date = $this->sma->fld($end_date);
        }
        if (!$this->Owner && !$this->Admin) {
        $user = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
        }

        $dateTmp = "DATE_FORMAT(".$this->db->dbprefix('sales').".date,'%m/%Y')";
        $condition = "if(".$this->db->dbprefix('sales').".biller_id = 5, 'A', if(".$this->db->dbprefix('sales').".biller_id = 6, 'B',if(".$this->db->                       dbprefix('sales').".biller_id = 7,'C','D'  )))";        


        $this->db
        ->select("date, ".$this->db->dbprefix('warehouses').".name, 
        CONCAT(".$this->db->dbprefix('warehouses').".name,'-',".$dateTmp.",'-', ".$condition.",".$this->db->dbprefix('sales').".invoice_no) as month," ." biller, customer,
        scan_no,unit_price,tin,cin,cst,total_discount, item_tax, shipping,subtotal,payment_status,sales.id as saleid,total_items,total,biller_id,tax_rate_id,grand_total,quantity", FALSE)
        ->from('sales')
        ->join('sale_items', 'sale_items.sale_id=sales.id', 'left')
        ->join('companies','companies.id=sales.customer_id', 'left')
        ->join('warehouses', 'warehouses.id=sales.warehouse_id', 'left')
        ->group_by('sales.id')
        ->order_by('sales.date desc');
        if ($biller) {
        $this->db->where('sales.biller_id', $biller);
        }
        if ($customerid) {
        $this->db->where('sales.customer_id', $customerid);
        }
        if ($warehouse) {
        $this->db->where('sales.warehouse_id', $warehouse);
        }

        if (($start_date) && ($end_date)) {
        $this->db->where($this->db->dbprefix('sales').'.date BETWEEN "' . $start_date . '" and "' . $end_date . '"');
        }
        /* if ($start_date) {
        $this->db->where($this->db->dbprefix('sales').'.date LIKE "' . $start_date . '"');
        }

        if ($end_date) {
        $this->db->where($this->db->dbprefix('sales').'.date LIKE "' . $end_date . '"');
        } */

        $q = $this->db->get();

        if ($q->num_rows() > 0) {
        foreach (($q->result()) as $row) {
        $data[] = $row;
        }
        } else {
        $data = NULL;
        }


        if (!empty($data)) 
        {
        $this->load->library('excel');
        $this->excel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle(lang('sales_report'));
        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A1', lang('date'));
        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('B1', lang('branch'));

        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('C1', lang('Vch_No.'));
        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('D1', lang('Voucher_Type'));

        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('E1', lang('Particulars'));
        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('F1', lang('TIN_No.'));
        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('G1', lang('CIN'));
        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('H1', lang('CST_No.'));

        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('I1', lang('Scan_No'));
        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('J1', lang('Product'));
        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('K1', lang('quantity'));
        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('L1', lang('Rate'));
        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('M1', lang('Sales_@__5%'));
        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('N1', lang('Output_Vat_@_5%'));
        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('O1', lang('Sales_@_14.5%'));
        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('P1', lang('Output_Vat_@_14.5%'));
        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('Q1', lang('Sales_@_0%'));
        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('R1', lang('Scanning_charge'));
        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('S1', lang('Scanning_Discount')); 
        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('T1', lang('Shipping'));
        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('U1', lang('Gross_Total'));

        $row = 2;
        $total = 0;
        $paid = 0;
        $balance = 0;
        $quantity= 0;
        $prdt_price = 0;
        $sale5=0.00;
        $output5=0.00;
        $sale145=0.00;
        $output145=0.00;

        $sale0=0.00;
        $discount=0; 


        foreach ($data as $data_row) 
        {

        $saleid=$data_row->saleid;
        $billerid=$data_row->biller_id;
        $gross_total= $data_row->grand_total + shipping;

        if($billerid==7)
        {
        $sale0=0;
        $discount=$data_row->total_discount;
        /*$scanqty=$data_row->quantity;
        if($scanqty==0.5)
        {
        $scanning_charge+=500;
        }
        else if($scanqty==1)
        {
        $scanning_charge+=1000;
        }*/
        $this->db->select("sum(`quantity`*1000) as scanning_charge", FALSE);
        $this->db->where('sale_id',$saleid);
        $queryres = $this->db->get('sale_items');
        if($queryres->num_rows() > 0)
        {
        foreach($queryres->result() as $queryres1)
        {
        $scanning_charge=$queryres1->scanning_charge;
        }
        }
        else
        {

        }

        }
        else
        {
        $scanning_charge=0;
        $discount=0;
        }
        if(($billerid==5) || ($billerid==6))
        {
        $this->db->select("sum( case when tax_rate_id = 1 then `net_unit_price`*`quantity` else 0 end) as sale0", FALSE);
        $this->db->where('sale_id',$saleid);
        $res1=$this->db->get('sale_items');
        if($res1->num_rows() > 0)
        {
        echo $billerid;
        foreach ($res1->result() as $row31)
        {

        $sale0=$row31->sale0;

        } 
        }
        else
        {

        }
        }


        $total0=$data_row->total;
        $this->db->select("GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT  product_name) as products,SUM(quantity)as prdtqty")
        ->from('sale_items')
        ->where('sale_id',$saleid);
        $q1 = $this->db->get();
        if ($q1->num_rows() > 0)
        {
        foreach (($q1->result()) as $row1) 
        {
        $products = $row1->products;
        $prdtqty = $row1->prdtqty;
        }
        }
        else
        {
        $products="";
        }

        $sql="select sum( case when tax_rate_id = 2 then net_unit_price*quantity else 0 end) as sale5,
        sum( case when tax_rate_id = 3 then net_unit_price*quantity else 0 end) as sale145,
        sum( case when tax_rate_id = 2 then item_tax else 0 end) as output5,
        sum( case when tax_rate_id = 3 then item_tax else 0 end) as output145
        from sma_sale_items
        where sale_id=".$saleid;

        $res=$this->db->query($sql);
        if($res->num_rows() > 0)
        {
        foreach ($res->result() as $row3)
        {
        $sale5=$row3->sale5;
        $output5=$row3->output5;
        $sale145=$row3->sale145;
        $output145=$row3->output145;

        }
        }

        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A' . $row, $this->sma->hrld($data_row->date));
        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('B' . $row, $data_row->name);
        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('C' . $row, $data_row->month);
        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('D' . $row, $data_row->biller);

        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('E' . $row, $data_row->customer);
        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('F' . $row, $data_row->tin);
        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('G' . $row, $data_row->cin);
        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('H' . $row, $data_row->cst);

        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('I' . $row, $data_row->scan_no);

        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('J' . $row, $products);
        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('K' . $row, $prdtqty);


        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('L' . $row, $data_row->total);
        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('M' . $row, $sale5);
        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('N' . $row, $output5);
        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('O' . $row, $sale145);
        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('P' . $row, $output145);
        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('Q' . $row, $sale0);
        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('R' . $row, $scanning_charge);
        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('S' . $row, $discount); 
        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('T' . $row, $data_row->shipping);
        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('U' . $row, $gross_total);

        $total += $data_row->subtotal;
        $paid += $data_row->item_tax;
        $row++;      
        }
        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('A')->setWidth(18);
        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('B')->setWidth(8);

        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('C')->setWidth(20);
        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('D')->setWidth(15);
        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('E')->setWidth(30);
        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('F')->setWidth(15);
        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('G')->setWidth(10);
        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('H')->setWidth(10);

        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('I')->setWidth(12);
        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('J')->setWidth(30);

        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('K')->setWidth(10);

        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('L')->setWidth(11);
        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('M')->setWidth(13);
        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('N')->setWidth(17);

        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('O')->setWidth(14);
        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('P')->setWidth(20);
        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('Q')->setWidth(12);
        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('R')->setWidth(18);
        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('S')->setWidth(20);
        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('T')->setWidth(12);
        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('U')->setWidth(14);

        $filename = 'sales_report';
        $this->excel->getDefaultStyle()->getAlignment()->setVertical(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::VERTICAL_CENTER);

        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('E2:E' . $row)->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);
        ob_clean();
        header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="' . $filename . '.xls"');
        header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
        ob_clean();
        $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($this->excel, 'Excel5');
        $objWriter->save('php://output');
        exit();     
        }
        else{

        $this->session->set_flashdata('error', lang('nothing_found')); 
        redirect('reports/sales_accounts');
        }

        }
```

Here is my browser view:
[image]

Can anyone please help me to fix this.. I am really in need of this.. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
ob_clean();
ob_start(); # added 
header('Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=UTF-8" ); # Improved with UTF charset
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="' . $filename . '.xls"'); 
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
ob_clean(); # remove this
```

if you want download this with 2003 and 2007 there are few changes to be done

```
2007 - file format xlsx
2003 - file format xls
```